# Word Add-Ins Office.js

Tags: office-js, word-addins

we do have the requirement that we have to write data in a .docx document, but we do have to do it in a batch process, not in a dialog, and would like to save the docx document.

In our case the user is working in our own WebApp and should be able to start the process of the Word-AddIn, which we created and he got over sideloading before.
One more question. The user would launch the Word Addin on the same host, as our WebApp runs. The request for data would also go to the same host. Do we really need for this scenario https or should http work either?

Is this possible? And if yes, how this process would be look like?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the batch process? Is this something that runs on a timer and you expect to update the document even if the addin is not activated? Or should we assume the addin is active at all times?

Comment: Hi Mavi, thanks for your response. Yes, the Addin 'll be active at all time! My idea is, that it will run on the same webserver as our app is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of the problem might be a bit limited - but:

- It doesn't matter which server the add-in is running, you'll need https. This just ensures that the data you transmit in either way is encrypted.
- You can definitely make sure your server and your add-in are having a conversation using WebSockets. (ex: Tell from the server that you want to save the document, or append something, publish that event and on the client side after receiving this just do what you needed to do)
- As another bonus, you can actually pin the add-in now, so you don't need to spend additional effort to keep it open:

  ```
  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
     <SourceLocation resid="readTaskPaneUrl" />
     <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
   </Action>
  ```

Comment: Hi Mavi, thank you very much! "HTTPS is necessary", this is what I need to know. Time for us to bring it all to https (was overdue). "As another bonus, you can actually pin the add-in now" I'm not sure if I see the bonus ... sorry.

Comment: You can pin the addin to the side, so you don't need to open / close it everytime. This is a relatively new feature :) Can you mark it as the answer if you think this solves your problem?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/01/26/pinnable-taskpane-in-outlook-2016/ Oh actually this might be only supported for Outlook at this stage